# vim using cmap to simplify search and replace regex

Tags: regex, vim

I need to indent case and default in C++ switch statements by 2 spaces manually.
So I add this line to my vimrc file:

```
cmap >c %s/\(\ case\ \|\ default:\)/\ \ \1/g
```

However, when I type :>c in vim, it results in:

```
       :%s/\(\ case\ |\ default:\)/\ \ \1/g
```

\| is expected instead of |,

Could someone tell me what's wrong in my cmap? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` caracter separates to commands. In this case it would be best to escape your `|` by using `<bar>` instead.

I think command would be more appropriate than a mapping, especially a `cmap`.

```
command! -range=% CaseFix <line1>,<line2>s/\(\ case\ \<bar>\ default:\)/\ \ \1/g
```

If you do want a mapping I would suggest a normal mode mapping with `<leader>`.

```
nnoremap <leader>cf :%s/\(\ case\ \<bar>\ default:\)/\ \ \1/g<cr>
```

Alternatively I think you would probably be better off to adjust your indention rules and just use `=` to re-indent the code. e.g. `gg=G` C/C++ indention rules are often governed by `'cindent'`, `'cinkeys'`, and `'cinoptions'`.

For more information see:

```
:h key-notation
:h :command
:h =
:h 'cindent'
:h 'cinkeys'
:h 'cinoptions'
```

Comment: I write C++ with Eclipse + Vrapper, instead of pure VIM. Vrapper's regular expression grammar is different from vim's. I have solved it in my [github](https://github.com/idealvin/etc). Thanks any way!

Answer (score 0):

Currently vim understands backslash before `|` as an attempt to escape it, hence the behavior, try adding one more backslash:

```
cmap >c %s/\(\ case\ \\|\ default:\)/\ \ \1/g
```